# Dictionary for New Latin words

Tags: resource-request, dictionary

Is there an online dictionary that contains many New Latin words with macrons?

I know there is already a post about dictionaries:

[Which online Latin dictionaries should I use and why?](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/867/which-online-latin-dictionaries-should-i-use-and-why)

However, the dictionaries mentioned there sometimes don't have a certain New Latin word or they have it, but they don't have macrons, thus making sometimes difficult to guess the pronunciation.

The tools I have found most useful are Pons online dictionary, which has some New Latin words, but often without macrons; Numen, the Latin lexicon, which also has a lot of New Latin words and even with macrons, but it does not have always the words; Wikipedia in Latin, which has a lot of New Latin words, but rarely with macrons. Glosbe dictionary, which has a lot of words, but often without macrons; Kindle version of Lexicon Recentis Latinitatis, which is one of the most useful ones, but it is a German edition and the translations frequently don't have macrons.

As long as one can find a word and it is in Wiktionary, it is possible to see the words with macrons, but unfortunately Wiktionary also has its limits.

So, is there an online dictionary that is to some extent specialized in New Latin words and that has macrons?

Answer (score 10):

The [*Lexicon Morganianum*](http://neolatinlexicon.org/home) (with a new website as of only a few months ago) is an excellent resource. It was originally compiled by David Morgan and Patrick Owens. It includes macrons and is exclusively for neo-Latin words, like ["radio."](http://neolatinlexicon.org/search/latin?search=radio)

The search-utility is not terribly good (as you can see from the above example). It certainly beats what I did earlier: saving a large Word document and using the "Find" function.

Comment: I made this community wiki. If someone with more knowledge of the project can add extra info (especially about the difference between the *adumbratio* and the *silva*), that would be helpful!